# ArrayList and toString

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, tostring

I'd like to ask that, how can i use ArrayList to store a toString(). I've got a class, with a toString  at the end, and i have to store the toString from the class into the ArrayList.

Like this : Music name , author , release year , currently playing
             String    , String , int          , boolean

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... what do you mean toString at the end? Do you mean you declared the method at the end of the class file? You need to be as specific as possible on this site and often post code too to get your question fully understood. Also welcome to StackOverFlow!

Comment: Where is your code, what have you tried already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hoping you have properly formatted text in your specific class's `toString()` method,
use

```
List<String> listDesired = new ArrayList<String>( 10 );
listDesired.add( myMusicDataClassInstance.toString() );
```

Comment: Why set the array list size to 10?

Comment: @luketorjussen: why not? the zero argument constructor does the same, just implicitly.

Comment: @home if it does it implicitly then why bother writing it too?

Comment: @luketorjussen - There is nothing wrong using which constructor for the object. 10 was just a coincidence. I Don't find a reason for down voting.

Comment: Me neither. @luketorjussen: IMO explicitly stating it is a good practice.

Comment: @Ravinder, I didn't down vote. I was just asking why you had done it.

Comment: @home, I can see why one would state it if you know how many items you were going to have, otherwise it's a bit confusing to read IMO

Comment: @luketorjussen - regarding downvote, I saw only challenging question from you and thought it might be you down voted. I am sorry if it were not you. And on SO most of the responses are based on the assumptions on what OP is expecting but not exact *deliverable* kind of things that a OP uses a CTRL+C here and a CTRL+V in his code. If that *Why* question was from the OP, I would have received it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `"" + x` trick so as to avoid `NullPointerException` in case an `x` is null:

```
public List<String> musicToString(List<Music> musicList) {
  final List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (Music m : musicList) strings.add("" + m);
  return strings;
}
```

This works because the concatenation operator `+` implicitly calls `String.valueOf` on all reference-typed operands.

You can also write `String.valueOf` explicitly, if that is your aesthetic preference. It also has the marginal benefit of definitely not instantiating a `StringBuilder` (although there's a good chance the compiler will avoid that anyway since it can see the empty string literal).

Comment: But maybe we want null to appear in the list?

Comment: This will make the string `null` to appear in the list. Using `m.toString()` will not make anything appear anywhere, except for an NPE in the console :)

Comment: You could also use String.valueOf(); in place of concatenation.

Comment: You SHOULD use String.valueOf() in place of concatenation

Comment: And why SHOULD I use it, @unbeli? I regularly use concatenation since it's shorter to write. Unless I'm writing performance-critical code, what's the harm? Can you elaborate? Or do you just like to downvote?

Comment: Because concatenating with an empty string is basically a hack. String.valueOf is easier to read. String.valueOf directly shows your intention. String.valueOf does not create a StringBuffer.

Comment: That's just an opinion. I personally find `""+m` much easier to read since it wastes little on the obvious, unlike `String.valueOf(m)`.

Comment: To be perfectly fair, what is easy to read is very much context-dependent. If you have a whole project consistently using `""+m` -- I worked on such projects -- then it's at the same time concise, readable, and showing the writer's intention with utmost clarity.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Basically, `"" + m` creates a new String object in the memory which is `""`, then calls `toString()` on `m` which involves creating another String object, and finally creates a third String object which is the concatenation of `""` and `m.toString()`. However, your answer doesn't deserve a -1, so I give you +1. Although `"" + m` is shorter, `m.toString()` is better as the performance is considered (or `String.valueOf()` to avoid NullPointerException).

Comment: @Eng.Fouad `""` is a compile-time constant and an interned singleton at runtime. The method `toString` creates a new `String` anyway. As I noted, if you really care about the last bit of performance, use `String.valueOf()` -- but if performance is the only reason, you're guilty of premature optimization 99% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Question is unclear, but if your objects already have toString() method defined you don't need to store them separately in array list. Just add the objects to arrayList and do `Collections.toString(yourList)`;

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `toString()` for that class and in `toString()` method define the business logic that will convert that string into `ArrayList` object.

Comment: It wouldn't be a proper override of the method, since `toString()` always returns `String`.  You could *overload* the method, but I don't see the benefit of doing that in this situation, either.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> listDesired = new ArrayList<String>( 10 );
```